# array to ObjectList angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
import { Board } from './board';

export class Notification {
    id : number ;       
    startDate : Date = null;
    endDate : Date = null;
    message : string = '';  
    notificationBoards: Board[] ;
}
```

Board class

```
export class Board {
    id : number = 0;
    name : string = '';     
    createDate : Date = null;
    createdBy : number ;    
}
```

Coponent class is

```
message.component.ts


///..


submitForm(obj) {  
      console.log("obj - "+obj);
      let notificationObj:Notification = new Notification();  
      let selectedBoard: Board[];
      notificationObj.startDate = obj.startDate;
      notificationObj.endDate = obj.endDate;
      notificationObj.message = obj.message;
      notificationObj.notificationBoards =  obj.board;
      console.log("notificationObj.notificationBoards"+notificationObj.notificationBoards.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < notificationObj.notificationBoards.length; i++) {
        console.log(":::"+notificationObj.notificationBoards[i] +":::");
        
      }


...///
```

I am able to add the notification but unable to add the board obj inside notification object. Board is a list of boards.
obj.board - is an array {10,20,...} which is boardId.
I want to add this array to Board[] and send to service layer.
let selectedBoard: Board[]; is the board list and I want to push notificationObj.notificationBoards[i] to  selectedBoard[i] and so on.
Basicaly want to add array to object list Board[].Can someone please help.

Comment: Java != javascript

Comment: You mentioned that `obj.board` is having array of ids, then type of `notificationBoards` should be number[] not the `board[]`. Please share sample obj data and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **obj.board** is a plain array of numbers (boardIds as you explained), **notificationObj.notificationBoards** is an array of **Board** objects.

Typescript would not allow you to convert an object array of type **Board** class into an array of number values..

**You'll have to map one array type to another** something like this.

```js
notificationObj.notificationBoards =  obj.board.map(boardId=>{
let boardObj:Board = new Board();
boardObj.id = boardId;   //since we have only one element (boardId), other fields of board object are not set.

return boardObj;
});
```

Thanks.